# SystemVerilog not recognizing constant: Error: Range must be bounded by constant expression

Tags: constants, declaration, system-verilog

In this short example, I want to simplify writing of signal width. With one signal, there is really no need to do this, but in my real code, I have many such signals and declaring them with the longer style wouldn't be appropriate.

Could you please enlighten me why I'm getting error for signal_2?

```
module sample #(parameter BYTE_WIDTH = 4);
    const int BIT_WIDTH = BYTE_WIDTH * 8;

    logic [BYTE_WIDTH * 8 -1 : 0] signal_1; // works
    logic [BIT_WIDTH -1 : 0] signal_2; // ** Error: Range must be bounded by constant expressions.
endmodule
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `const` variable is assigned its value at *run time*. Which is too late: the width of your variable `signal_2` needed to be fixed at *compile time*. So, what you need is a `localparam`, which (like a `parameter`) is fixed at compile time, but (unlike a `parameter`) cannot be overridden from outside:

```
module sample #(parameter BYTE_WIDTH = 4);
    localparam BIT_WIDTH = BYTE_WIDTH * 8;

    logic [BYTE_WIDTH * 8 -1 : 0] signal_1; 
    logic [BIT_WIDTH -1 : 0] signal_2; 
endmodule
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/2fKU

Comment: Ah, so const isn't really constant :D ok... Thank you very much :)

Comment: @TomášViksPilný Well, it's constant, because you're not allowed to change it. But it's value is fixed too late for your purposes.